# Is there a way for a method in a derived class to not override the base class method

Tags: objective-c

I am currently in the process of Learning Objective-C coming from a c++ background. I wanted to know if there was a way for the derived class method that has the same signature as the base class to not override it.
I read that every method in Objective-C is virtual.Are there any ways in which a derived class does not override the base class method be simulated ?

I have the following two classes

```
@interface foo_base : NSObject
-(void) base_method;
-(void) shared_method;
@end


@interface foo_der : foo_base
-(void) der_method;
-(void) shared_method;
@end
```

and when I use it like this

```
foo_base *b = [[foo_der alloc]init];
[b shared_method]; //Derived class method will be called.
```

I know I could do something like this inside the derived class method

```
[super  shared_method] //call base class method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in Objective-C if a derived class implements a base class method with the same signature, it is always overridden. You could create a "helper" function like this if you really want to access the base class method directly.

```
- (void) callSuperSharedMethod { 
    [super sharedMethod]; 
}
```